# Update Yii2 project to php 7.2

Tags: yii2, php-7.2

I have are project writed on php 7.1 https://github.com/triest/Yii-curse

When you run on the server PHP version 7.2, you get the error:

> (W:\domains\Yii-curse\yii\basic\web/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\Yii-curse\yii\basic\web\index.php on line 7

But these files are in place!

Comment: i never faced this error upgrading to 7.2 can you show the index.php file inside your `web` as i suspect the file it is trying to include most probably related to the config has a path issue, i mean that what it looks like from the error.

Comment: Index.php ->[link](https://github.com/triest/Yii-curse/blob/master/yii/basic/web/index.php)

Comment: you look to be in windows, can you check by replacing `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` with  `require __DIR__ . str_replace('/',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,'/../vendor/autoload.php');` and check if it moves to the next line? as the issue seems to be with the directory separator and windows uses \ .

Comment: No change.  I use openserver and apach-PHP-7.2-x64

Answer (score 0):

Your server pointing to right file but it is unable to find autoload.php in vendor, so make sure to double check.

As I can see you have composer.json on two places so probably you done composer install from wrong folder.